# Find maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths of length $k$ in a tree with no restrictions for the paths

Tags: dynamic-programming, trees

I am working currently on Path-Packing problems and found this Book:

https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/Algorithms-JeffE.pdf

My question is about exercise 23b on page 184.

Here is a description of the problem :

Assume $T$ is a tree (T is not necessarily a binary tree) with $n$ nodes and root node $r$. For a given $k \in \mathbb{N}$ find a maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths of length $k$ in $T$. 2 Paths are vertex-disjoint if they don't share any vertex.

In the book, there is one more assumption made about the paths. This assumption says that every path is going towards the root node.  I was able to show with Greedy that I can find a maximum vertex-disjoint set of paths of length $k$ but only if we assume that every path is directed toward the root node. My question is now, what if we don't make restrictions regarding the paths? For example, it is possible that 2 children from the same node are in one of the paths of the optimal solution. (Optimal solution is obviously the maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths).

My first approach was to use Greedy again but it didn't work because for Greedy it's not clear if the path should go toward the root, or maybe first toward the root, and after a few steps go back toward (another) leaf node.

My next approach would be dynamic programming. Here I'm struggling a little bid and I'm not sure if I am on the right track. I first tried to define a function $f(v,i)$ which says what is the best optimal solution at the subtree of the particular node if $v$ has position $i$ in one of paths of the solution. But I was not able to define the recursive formula.  I hope someone can give me a hint or is interested in discussing the issue.